# Interpretation of Integral of Differential 3-Form over 3-Manifold in Engineering?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-analysis, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, de-rham-cohomology

So, the standard interpretation of a differential 1-form's integral over a compact, connected, oriented 1-manifold is work, and the standard interpretation of a differential 2-form's integral over a compact, connected, oriented 2-manifold is flux, in engineering parlance.

What would be an interpretation of a differential 3-form's integral over a compact, connected, oriented 3-manifold (say, a submanifold of the 6D c-space of a robot arm) in standard engineering parlance?

I'm trying to motivate differential forms as the generalizations of tangent vector fields over curves and normal vector fields over surfaces in Calc III to my Calc III students, but it's difficult to motivate something without knowing its interpretation. (I only actually assign problems on 3- and higher-form integrals as Extra Credit problems, but present the notions of 0-, 1-, 2-, and 3-forms on open, connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$, their wedge products, their exterior derivatives, and their Hodge stars as a parallel and unifying theory to the notions of functions, vector fields, cross products, and grad, curl, and div as part of the standard lecture. I also illustrate 0- and 1-forms and their Hodge stars on $\mathbb{R}$ to explain why there "is no" de Rham cohomology of open, connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and why continuous 1-forms [Hodge stars of functions] therefore always have an antiderivative on compact intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ as part of FTC ["Exterior derivatives are always zero and points separate"].) Any actual examples of integrals of 3- (and higher-)forms in engineering work to illustrate would be GREATLY appreciated.

[Here is the Extra Credit problem http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/ec.pdf.

Here are some scripts to solve the last two problems https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/482/
http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/ec-p23Form.nb
http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/ec-p2DiffForm.wxmx
http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/ec-p3DiffForm.wxmx.]

Comment: If your 3-form is positive, you can think of the integral as the total mass of the given density. This is how I would motivate this definition (starting, for simplicity, with domains in $R^3$).

Comment: While I really appreciate the help, I think (and, the function could take on negative values if it were an electric charge density, e.g.) this is the integral of a scalar function over a 3-manifold, not a 3-form. Thanks again

Comment: If you think through it, when you say that you are integrating a function over a 3-manifold, you are really integrating a 3-form (or a 3-dimensional density).

Comment: I don't wish to get into a knock down-drag out, but the situation I'm envisioning is that the 3-manfold is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$ or some 6-manifold, e.g., and the 3-form is "defined" on the 6-manifold, so its Hodge star is another 3-form on the 6-manifold, not "easily" (?) a 0-form on the 3-manifold. If that doesn't clear things up, I'll just thank you for you help at this point and cease commenting back.

Comment: (Reposted here https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44539/interpretation-of-integral-of-differential-3-form-over-3-manifold-in-engineering)

Comment: I do not wish to add fuel to fire … but I think the sense of MoisheKohan's remark is that the (oriented) $3$-manifold inherits a canonical volume form from a metric on the ambient $6$-manifold, and both $\omega$ and $\star\omega$ are scalar functional multiples of that. We certainly do this with flux interpretations of integrating $2$-forms over surfaces.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks so much

Comment: P.S. one of your remarks in your handout is wrong. Of course you can do work and flux integrals of a vector field in higher dimensions. These are integrals of $1$- and $(n-1)$-forms respectively; flux across an (oriented) hypersurface always makes sense (and there is the generalized Divergence Theorem in the case of a boundary).

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess you're right: there is a notion of line integral of vector field on manifolds "outside of $\mathbb{R}^3$" (but there's no notion of "curl" in > 4D [box operator in pseudo-Riemannian 4D?], so it's hard to tell if a vector field is conservative?); I'm not sure the normal bundle for a 2-manifold  "outside of $\mathbb{R}^3$" would be a line bundle (of course, there's a stable normal bundle) and so the naive notion of dotting with the unit normal vector field might not work for flux integral. But, you're right and I'm wrong

Comment: Well, of course even though there's no curl, there is still the exterior derivative in dimensions $\ge 4$, and so whenever $H^1=0$, you have the analogue of the curl test. No, of course the normal bundle has rank $n-2$. I was talking about flux across *hypersurfaces* (in any Riemannian manifold, in fact).

Comment: (One could take the musical isomorphism of a tangent vector field via the Riemannian metric to get a 1-form, take its exterior derivative, and then if that's zero and the period of the 1-form over all generators of $H_{1,dR}(M^n)$ were 0, conclude the vector field is grad of a scalar field; but, at that point, one is kind-of in differential form land, by some metrics.)

Comment: I was confused and talking about dimension 2 submanifolds for flux integrals; my apologies

Comment: Yes, definitely, there is a notion of tangent vector field and dotting it into the unit tangent vector field along an oriented curve to do line integrals; I'll have to amend the handout for posterity's sake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126176/discussion-between-jeffrey-rolland-and-ted-shifrin).

Comment: Doesn't look like I'm going to get an answer for this one; thanks to everyone who read